# Change of SelectedItem triggers get instead of set

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selecteditem

I have a ListBox bound to a List and the selectedItem is also bound to a List with typically one entry. So for the selectItem I get the first one in the bound list:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Definition.DatatypeDefinition.SpecifiedValues}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding ObjectValue[0], Mode=TwoWay}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding AttributeDefinition.IsEditable, Converter={StaticResource AttributeEditableConverter}}"
         Name="dataField">
 </ListBox>
```

I expected that if I select another Item the set Operation of the bound property would be fired, but instead only the get Operation is fired. This is how my ObjectValue looks like:

```
public List<EnumValue> Values 
{
    get
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
        return this.values;
    }
}


public override object ObjectValue
{
    get => this.Values;
    set
    {
        if (!(value is IEnumerable<EnumValue> enumValues))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"The value to set is not an IEnumerable<EnumValue>.");
        }

        this.values.Clear();
        this.values.AddRange(enumValues);
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Why is my set Operation not initiated when I change the SelectedItem in the Listbox? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is my set Operation not initiated when I change the SelectedItem in the Listbox?

Because you don't bind to the `ObjectValue` property:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding ObjectValue[0]}"
```

You bind to the first value in whatever `ObjectValue` returns so the setter of `ObjectValue` is never invoked.

`SelectedItem="{Binding ObjectValue}" binds to` ObjectValue` and will try to invoke its setter whenever a new item is selected.